# How to only allow a specific user to create new users in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

There are a lot of posts and discussions about restricting read/write access to specific users in the Firebase real-time database. However, I am not able to find a way to restrict the creation of new users to only a specific user/admin.

My application consists of a manager and employees. Only the manager should be able to add new users (employees) to the database along with having access to specific data which employees cannot access. From my understanding, the API which Firebase provides means that any client can create new users.
Could someone please guide me on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as follows:

Firstly, create an `admins` node in your database to which you add the admin/manager user(s) with their userId, as follows:

```
- admins
    - Br8kiG5....
- users
    -  Abcd88676....
      - ....
    -  JHgU76hgh....
      - ....
```

Secondly, set-up some security rules as follows,

```
{
  "rules": {

      "users": {
            ".write": "auth != null && root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            ".read": .....
            ".indexOn": .....
      },

       .....

  }
}
```

Thirdly, implement the Firebase authentication in your app and only the user(s) listed under the `admins` database node will be able to write under the `users` node.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer!  
I just stumbled upon the Custom Claims feature of Firebase. I'm slightly confused by this. Do you know if this feature is a replacement of what you have shown in your answer? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can also use Custom Claims to implement such a security mechanism, as detailed here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims. One of the advantages is that "no additional processing or lookup is needed to check for admin permissions." However, note that you can only set the Claim "from a privileged server environment by the Firebase Admin SDK" (e.g. from your own server or through a Cloud Function) which can be a bit more complex than the solution proposed in my answer.

Comment: An alternative is setting a field inside the users (I used  `superadmin` ) and replace the rule with something like this:  `auth != null &&  root.child('/userdata/'+auth.uid+'/userRole').val() === 'superadmin'",`